# Lost with fibonacci series on TASM Assembly

Tags: loops, assembly, x86-16, tasm

I got an assignment from university to calculate fibonacci series of 10 elements when we know the first 2 elements.
I have been trying to do this in the past hours but I got lost on the way.

This is my code:

```
IDEAL
MODEL small
STACK 100h
DATASEG

Fiburnachi db 0, 1, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?, ?
TenTimes db 8


CODESEG

start:
    mov ax, @data
    mov ds, ax
    xor ax, ax
    xor bx, bx
    xor cx, cx


    mov cl, [TenTimes]
    lea bx, [Fiburnachi]
    FibLoop:
        mov al, [bx]       //This is my first attempt.
        add al, [bx+1]     //i have tried using only the "ax" register,
        inc [bx]           //i can't seem the find the correct way to
        mov [bx], al       //store the value I have in al (last result)

        mov al, [bx]       //This Doesn't work I dunno why really.
        mov dl, [bx+1]
        add al, dl
        mov [bx+1], al
        inc [bx]

    FibLoop
```

I think that my understanding of correct looping and assigning through array indexes is wrong.

What is the correct way of doing this? Will I have to use 2 registers for the Calculation itself?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both attempts are close, both are missing the `loop` command.

The first would work like this:

```
mov al, [bx]
add al, [bx+1]
inc [bx]           
mov [bx+1], al // need to write to the next position
```

The second:

```
mov al, [bx]
mov dl, [bx+1]
add al, dl
inc [bx] // need to increment before writing
mov [bx+1], al
```

and finish both with `loop FibLoop`.

P.S. it's not entirely clear from your question, but these are 2 separate attempts, right? they won't work together in the same application :-)

Answer (score 1):

I don't know TASM, but I suspect that inc [bx] is going to increment a byte (or word?) in memory as opposed to incrementing bx, in which case the syntax is inc bx.

alternate example

```
        lea     bx,[Fiburnachi+2]
fib0:   mov     al,[bx-2]
        add     al,[bx-1]
        mov     [bx],al
        inc     bx              ;increment bx, not memory?
        loop    fib0
```